# JSON node undefined as variable

Tags: javascript, axios

Using axios to return an object. I'm able to get the keys, etc. In this case, I'm trying to get the value for a child node "Id". When I pass in the Nodes as variables ([trait] [trait2]), I get "undefined". When I pass in [trait].Id it works. What am I doing wrong here? I tried different versions of Arr and Map, but I can't get those to work, but wonder if it's overkill anyway...

```
  var trait = req.params.trait;
  var trait2 = req.params.trait2;

   axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
      const resp_data = JSON.parse(xj.xml2json(response.data, { compact: true, spaces: 2 }));
       if ( trait2="" ) {
         resp2= resp_data.Application[trait];
        } else {
          resp2= resp_data.Application[trait];
                console.log(resp2);
//CONSOLE RESPONSE:
//    {
//      Id: { _text: '34A9BCAA-4322-F5AA-9390-1639C06614D2' },
//      BudgetedJointInd: { _text: 'Y' },.....
//    }
                trait2 = String(trait2); //="Id"
                console.log(resp2[trait2]); //RETURNS UNDEFINED
//CONSOLE RESPONSE:
//undefined
                console.log(resp2.Id); //WORKS CORRECTLY
//CONSOLE RESPONSE:
//{ _text: '34A9BCAA-4322-F5AA-9390-1639C06614D2' }
        }
       res.status(200).send(resp2.Id);   //WORKS CORRECTLY
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Comment: As some general advice, when you `console.log()` something, it is *extremely* helpful to accompany the value with a short message so that in the log output you can identify which value goes with which log statement.

Comment: Yes, 100%. Edited the code.

Comment: Is it possible that the value of `trait2` is not a string with only the characters "I" and "d"? Could there be a space or something? You could try `console.log("trait2: [" + trait2 + "]");` or something like that.

Comment: And/or log `trait2.length` and make sure it is 2 and not some other value.

Comment: That was what I needed. trait2 was empty in the else statement. I don't understand why it doesn't get passed correctly to the else block. Still, I just reset it within the block to fix the issue! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Oh I see the problem now! Your `if ()` comparison is wrong - it should be `==` or `===`, not `=`.

Comment: Appreciate your help!